# Куда уходят SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms, webforms

```
protected void btnsearch_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string find = "SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE(Name like '%' + @name + '%' or Autor like '%' + @autor + '%' or Editor like '%' + @editor + '%' or Year like '%' + @year + '%' or About like '%' + @about + '%' or Type like '%' + @type + '%')";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(find, con);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    comm.Parameters.Add("@autor", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    comm.Parameters.Add("@editor", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    comm.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    comm.Parameters.Add("@about", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    comm.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

    con.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = comm;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "picture");
    da.Fill(ds, "name");
    da.Fill(ds, "autor");
    da.Fill(ds, "editor");
    da.Fill(ds, "year");
    da.Fill(ds, "about");
    da.Fill(ds, "type");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

Вот код отвечающий за обработку клика по btnsearch. Он работает корректно - реализует поиск по БД и корректно выводит GridView1. 
Теперь сам вопрос: Необходимо в другой функции(последующей сортировки по результатам поиска) узнать что было введено в TextBox1.Text. Каким образом эту информацию возможно достать?

Comment: Нельзя ли просто сохранить значение `TextBox1.Text` в переменной?

Comment: Это хорошая идея, спасибо. Но я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы переменная была видна в других функциях? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сохранить значение `TextBox1.Text` в переменной:

```
private string textBoxValue;
protected void btnsearch_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxValue = TextBox1.Text;
    // остальной код
}

private void otherFunction()
{
    if (textBoxValue != null)
    {
        // можно использовать переменную `textBoxValue` здесь.
        Console.Write(textBoxValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, уважаемый!
Я как раз не знал как работать с одной переменной в разных функциях.
А не подскажите как аналогичный трюк провернуть, скажем, с GridView? (Есть GridView1 на странице, сгенерированный функцией, получить в другую функцию результат сгенерированного GridView)

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron Как мне кажется, разница там не большая, только `GridView` вместо `string`. Но если ещё не понятно, можно задать новый вопрос.

Comment: Да, думаю стало понятней. Спасибо за ответ - он важен для меня.

Comment: textBoxValue упорно стоит в null. С чем такое может быть связанно? Использовал приведеный Вами код.

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron  Если otherFunction вызывается до btnsearch_Click1, то переменная не определена.

Comment: а другие варианты?

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron Ну, трудно сказать, потому что не вижу ваш код. Если у вас новый вопрос, пожалуйста [задавайте его](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). В комментариях не очень удобно.